# Not possible to set input file in linux command running from .NET Core

Tags: c#, linux, bash, docker, .net-core

I'm running .NET Core app on the linux docker container

When I call the command from the linux terminal it works well:

```
./darknet detector test -out result.json < data/file-list.txt
```

But when I start the process from the .NET Core I see error. Process runner method:

```
public static string RunCommand(string command, string args)
    {
        var process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = command,
                Arguments = args,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };

        process.Start();

        process.WaitForExit();

        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    return @$"{output}{Environment.NewLine}-------------------------------{Environment.NewLine}{error}";
}
```

Calling code:

```
string args = @$"detector test -out result.json < data/file-list.txt";
string output = ProcessRunner.RunCommand("./darknet", args);
```

Here is the part of the output:

```
Cannot load image "<"
STB Reason: can't fopen
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Your linux shell has a special interpretation of the "<" character, to read in a file as input to the process. Dotnet does not process that character, it's passing it as an argument, but the argument of "<" is not valid for that application.

Comment: @BurnsBA Do I understand correctly that it is not possible to do it using .net core? Are there any workarounds? Like creating a file with command and executing it?

Comment: You can read the text file into the process's standard input.

Comment: @Eldar Can I ask you to post an answer with the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the process's standard input once you set the `RedirectStandartInput` to true while starting your process. Here is an example how to write :

```
        var process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "./ConsoleApp1.exe",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true, // here you need
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
            }
        };

        process.Start();
        using var file = File.OpenRead("./1.txt");
        using var reader = new StreamReader(file);
        while (true)
        {
            var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) break; // you can use some other stoping decision 
            await process.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync(line);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but in this case the program freezes on the `process.WaitForExit();`
I also noticed that it freezes when I don't set input file. In the terminal in asks me to to enter the file path manually and infinitely waits when I do that

Comment: I think that the problem is that we set standard input after process started

Comment: @AlexZaitsev Ah pardon then the process is expecting a file name instead of the content of the file I misinterpreted that. So `await process.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync("./1.txt");` should be enough.

Comment: Tried to use the last one but it is still freezes. Maybe there are some ways to emulate entering the answer when script asks to enter the file path?

Comment: You can read the output if the line matches the string that asks for the file path then you write to the input may be. @AlexZaitsev